Add Web Components to Electron with the preload script and context isolation
Add Web Components to an Electron with the preload script and context isolation
Problem
I'm trying to implement complex Web Components in my Electron application with the preload script. Context isolation must remain enabled as I need access to the contextBridge API for main-to-renderer process communication. However, this prevents me from accessing the customElements.define function, which I need to register the Web Components. Using the renderer script to add the Web Components is not possible, because I am rendering third party websites in my Electron App, which I would like to modify with the Web Components.
Current Setup
// main.ts
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    contextIsolation: true,  // Required for contextBridge
    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
  }
});

// preload.ts
class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = '<p>My Custom Element</p>';
  }
  // Way more logic in here
}

// This fails with context isolation enabled
customElements.define('my-element', MyCustomElement);

Error Message
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'define')

Additional Steps
I have also tried to add a the Web Component as new Vue Application to the renderer Process, but runs also into troubles, because it is missing the ssrContext.modules.
Question
How can I use Web Components in an Electron application while keeping context isolation enabled? Disabling context isolation isn't an option as I need the contextBridge API for secure IPC communication between main and renderer processes.
Technical Details

Electron version: 31.0.2

